# How to render partial view to string with link generation and on a seperate thread

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, httpcontext

I am using razor pages to generate my email but I ran into some issues.
When using a separate thread to minimize latency until the page posts-back:

```cs
Task.Run(async () => {
    // Send email code
}
```

The code I used to render partials to string was using `IHttpContextAccessor` like this:

```cs
var actionContext = new ActionContext(_contextAccessor.HttpContext, _contextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());
```

which works to generate links but fails when using it on a different thread  since the `HttpContext` is scoped and is already disposed.
I then tried to use:

```cs
using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() { RequestServices = scope.ServiceProvider };
```

which worked on a separate thread but failed when using `Url.PageLink` in my email templates with the error `InvalidOperationException: Could not find an IRouter associated with the ActionContext. If your application is using endpoint routing then you can get a IUrlHelperFactory with dependency injection and use it to create a UrlHelper, or use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.LinkGenerator.` .
I also tried to add routing to the `HttpContext` but that didn't change the error:

```cs
httpContext.Features.Set<IRoutingFeature>(new RoutingFeature());
httpContext.Request.RouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
```

Full code:

```cs
public class ViewRenderer
{
    private readonly IRazorViewEngine _razorViewEngine;
    private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
    private readonly IModelMetadataProvider _modelMetadataProvider;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public ViewRenderer(
        IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
        IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider,
        IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _modelMetadataProvider = modelMetadataProvider;
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync<T>(string viewName, T model)
    {
        using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() { RequestServices = scope.ServiceProvider };
        httpContext.Features.Set<IRoutingFeature>(new RoutingFeature());
        httpContext.Request.RouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, httpContext.GetRouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

        var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, false);

        if (viewResult.View == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} could not be found");
        }

        var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary<T>(_modelMetadataProvider, new ModelStateDictionary())
        {
            Model = model
        };

        using var sw = new StringWriter();

        var viewContext = new ViewContext(
            actionContext,
            viewResult.View,
            viewDictionary,
            new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
            sw,
            new HtmlHelperOptions()
        );

        await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);

        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

Is there any way for me to be able to generate links and not depend on the `HttpContext` of the request triggering this in the first place?

Comment: looks like you cannot use `IUrlHelper` in your email templates, instead try using a `LinkGenerator`. You may have to replace all the references to `IUrlHelper` in your email templates manually or write some code to replace them with equivalent code using `LinkGenerator` before actually parsing the templates.